# OSGi example project injection problem

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, osgi, code-injection

I'm having a problem with an example of OSGi as a maven project.

NetBeans: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-osgi-declarativeservices.html or there is a non-Netbeans version which yields identical results (blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_124_osgi_declarative_services)

I've tried going through both sets of instructions on two different platforms OSX/windows and I always end up with the same problem. I've been deploying to stable glassfish 3.1.

I've zipped up my projects that I created in one of my attempts and they can be found here: https://infra01.gimi.ox.ac.uk:8443/~douglas/problems/OSGiMavenProblem-20110616.zip

The only change I've made compared to the instructions is that I found I have to change the org.apache.felix.scr.annotations dependency to 1.4 because of:

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.felix:maven-scr-plugin:1.7.0:scr
>   (generate-scr-scrdescriptor) on
>   project helloservice: Please use
>   org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr.annotations
>   version 1.4.0 or newer.

All seems to go according to plan until the very end. I deploy the Web Client Application, but I get an injection problem:

> HTTP Status 500 -
>
> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> descriptionThe server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   PWC1392: Error instantiating servlet
>   class
>   com.mycompany.mavenhellowebclient.HelloClient
>   root cause
>
> com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
>   Error creating managed object for
>   class
>   com.mycompany.mavenhellowebclient.HelloClient
>   root cause
>
> com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionException:
>   Exception attempting to inject
>   Env-Prop:
>   com.mycompany.mavenhellowebclient.HelloClient/helloService@Field-Injectable
>   Resource. Class name =
>   com.mycompany.mavenhellowebclient.HelloClient
>   Field
>   name=helloService@java.lang.String@@@
>   into class
>   com.mycompany.mavenhellowebclient.HelloClient
>   root cause
>
> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup
>   failed for
>   'java:comp/env/com.mycompany.mavenhellowebclient.HelloClient/helloService'
>   in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}
>   [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup
>   failed for 'hello-service' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.mycompany.mavenhellowebclient.HelloClient/helloService}
>   [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   hello-service not found]]  root cause
>
> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup
>   failed for 'hello-service' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming,
>   com.sun.enterprise.naming.logicalName=java:comp/env/com.mycompany.mavenhellowebclient.HelloClient/helloService}
>   [Root exception is
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   hello-service not found]  root cause
>
> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
>   hello-service not found

Any suggestions would be much appreciated as I'm really stuck in my tracks at the moment.

Douglas